# Browserify Requiring Modules within Modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I'm trying, with `Browserify`, to enable `node.js` like modules in a `socket.io` web client.  I'm having problems requiring modules within required modules.

`main.js` requires `client.js`, which requires `admin.js`

`client.js` require path is relative to `main.js` location in the filesystem.

`admin.js` require path is relative to `client.js` location in the filesystem.

`browserify main.js -o client.packaged.js` produces a file with `client.js` embedded.  `admin.js` is required when an event is fired in `client.js`.  When this event fires, I get the following error:

`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../../../modules/admin/admin.js'`

I've tried changing the path to be relative to the browserified bundle and relative to `client.js`, both result in the error above, just different paths.

I've got Chrome open with `--alow-file-access-from-files`, so I know that shouldn't be part of the problem.

In the source map produced by `browserify`, `admin.js` is not anywhere, so it must not be finding it for some reason.

How do you correctly use relative paths within modules to require other modules when using `browserify`?

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Edit - Added source below to help clarify**

**main.js**

```
//Include the client
var client = require('../../base/client/client.js').client;

//Start when document is ready
$(function() {
    console.log(client);
    client.start();
});
```

**client.js**

```
var client = new Object();
client.start = function() {
    //Server specific information
    var IP = 'localhost';
    var PORT = '1337';

    //Flags
    //SSL - true for secured connections
    //DEBUG - true to enable console.log() messages
    var SSL = false;
    var DEBUG = true;

    //Locations of modules to include
    var MODULE_LOCATIONS = [
        '../../modules/admin/admin.js'
    ];

    //Builds an array of modules to start
    var MODULES = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < MODULE_LOCATIONS.length; i++) {
        MODULES.push(require(MODULE_LOCATIONS[i]));
    }

    var socket = io.connect(getConnectionString());    
    socket.on('connection', function(socket) {
        client.onConnection(socket);

        //Load modules
        for (var i = 0; i < MODULES.length; i++) {
            MODULES[i].start(socket, io);
        }
    });

    //Returns a connection string to the socket.io server
    function getConnectionString() {
        if (SSL) {
            return 'https://' + IP + ':' + PORT;
        } else {
            return 'http://' + IP + ':' + PORT;
        }
    }
};
module.exports.client = client;
```

**admin.js**

```
//Events
var SYSTEM_STATS = 'system_stats';
var start = function(socket, io) {
    socket.on(SYSTEM_STATS, function(data) {
        admin.onSystemStats(socket, data);
    });
}
module.exports.start = start;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Locations of modules to include
var MODULE_LOCATIONS = [
    '../../modules/admin/admin.js'
];

//Builds an array of modules to start
var MODULES = [];
for (var i = 0; i < MODULE_LOCATIONS.length; i++) {
    MODULES.push(require(MODULE_LOCATIONS[i]));
}
```

So yeah, browserify does static analysis. This means it reads and "understands" your code at a statement level, but it doesn't actually execute it. This type of construct defeats the static analysis's capabilities and thus browserify does not detect that the `client.js` module depends on `admin.js`. Remove this extra metaprogramming logic and put in a plain vanilla `require('../../modules/admin/admin.js')` and I think you'll be good to go.

Comment: The point is relative paths are relative to the file they are contained in. Your sentence makes it sound to me like you think the directory containing "main.js" becomes some sort of base path and then other files can require things relative to that. As always, code is clearer than English for questions like this. In addition to  file contents, showing the layout of directories and files will also help folks solve your problem.

Comment: I guess I got a little bit too clever with this approach.  I figured there was some mis-communication so I dumped the source to help.  Thank you for your help!